# React worse practice: fatter state or DOM manipulation?

Tags: reactjs, dom, svg

I have an `<svg />` element into which I render several `<g />`s and `<circle />`s stored via `useState()`. The `<line />`s are added to and removed from the `<svg />` by mutating the DOM directly through `append(), removeChild, insertBefore(), etc.`

Since in React you're not really supposed to mutate the DOM directly, I'm wondering if to switch over to storing the `<lines />`s with `useState()` and rendering them that way (again, just like I'm already doing with my `<g />`s and `<circles />`s. However, that would increase the amount of state being stored and managed, which should be kept to a minimum according to React best practices (?).

Btw, so far I have been getting away with not storing the `<line />`s in the state because, based on their ids, I can query the DOM and calculate the relationships between the elements. This is because I was told to keep state at a minimum. However, a potential pro to storing the `<lines />`s in the state would be that the code logic to calculate relationships might be simpler.

So essentially the question is between (A) fattening up the state (and maybe easier relationship lookup) but avoiding direct DOM manipulation vs (B) keeping a smaller state but directly modifying the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

React, in my humble opinion, is not perfectly suitable to work with SVG. However you can use the D3 library within a React app. Here is an [example](https://medium.com/welldone-software/d3-and-react-working-together-353d12c2a3bc).

Comment: I was hoping to avoid using a library but I'm starting to look at react dnd.